# Google Maps API - multiple markers works on localhost, not on server?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a newb to this site and a bit of a hack programmer so I hope this works. I'm trying to implement the use of google maps API in my HTML/Javascript code, I've been using it for some time without issue to display single maps and single markers. However, I am introducing a new type of product to my web store, and for those items I need to display multiple markers on the google map that pops up when the product is clicked on. (The new products are digital maps where formerly I only had printed maps.)

Now on to my problem: everything works as it should when I execute the code from my PC (i.e. stored on my 'C:\' drive), but when I upload it to my website server, the google maps only work for the store items that have ONE marker associated with them, and I get no error messages of any sort when the digital maps that are to have multiple markers don't display properly. More specifically, the map opens up in a div that is normally hidden upon being summoned by a click event, and this div just remains hidden when i click on any of the digital maps.

Do I need a google maps API "key" to display more than one marker like I'm trying to do? I don't have one, not sure where I got the key that I have listed in my code at current, I think I got it off google developers page at one point.

Applicable code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDkmV2jHK_Be-3aG80eDF3APa5idTzbpZ4&sensor=false">
```

My function with the google map callup:

```
function initializeMap(lakeNumber, bigImage4Size) 
{        
var latitude = lakeArray[lakeNumber][8];
var longitude = lakeArray[lakeNumber][9];
var mapTitle = lakeArray[lakeNumber][0];
var lakeNotes = lakeArray[lakeNumber][12];
var zoomLevel = parseInt(lakeArray[lakeNumber][15]);
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var numOfLakes = 1;
var lakesString = "haww";
var lakesAsArray = [];
var temp = "";
var mapOptions = {          
    center: myLatlng,          
    zoom: zoomLevel,          
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN        
    };        

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); 

if(lakeArray[lakeNumber][14].search("Digital")>=0)                                  //if product clicked was digital map
{
    lakesString = lakeArray[lakeNumber][16];

    for(y = 0; y < numLakes; y++)                   //turns string with separated lakes into an array by breaking it up at commas
    {
        lakesAsArray[y] = lakesString.substring(0,lakesString.indexOf(","));            
        lakesString = lakesString.substring(lakesString.indexOf(",") + 2,lakesString.length);
        if(lakesString.length<=1)
            break;
    }
    numOfLakes = lakesAsArray.length;

    for(d = 0; d < numOfLakes; d++)
    {
        temp = lakesAsArray[d];
        lakesAsArray[d] = new Array(3);

        for (p = 0; p < numLakes; p++)
        {
            if(lakeArray[p][0].search(temp)>=0)                 //checks if correct product has been "scanned"  
            {
                    lakesAsArray[d][0] = temp;  //assigns lake title
                    lakesAsArray[d][1] = lakeArray[p][8];                   //assigns lake latitude
                    lakesAsArray[d][2] = lakeArray[p][9];                   //assigns lake longitude
                    p = numLakes - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    lakesAsArray[0] = new Array(3);
    lakesAsArray[0][0] = lakeArray[lakeNumber][0];   //assigns lake title
    lakesAsArray[0][1] = lakeArray[lakeNumber][8];   //assigns lake latitude
    lakesAsArray[0][2] = lakeArray[lakeNumber][9];    //assigns lake longitude
}

for(c = 0; c < numOfLakes; c++)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lakesAsArray[c][1], lakesAsArray[c][2]),
    map: map,
    title: lakesAsArray[c][0],
    });



}
document.getElementById("lake_label").innerHTML = mapTitle;
if(lakeArray[lakeNumber][14].search("Digital")>=0)
    {
    document.getElementById("lake_notes").innerHTML = "<FONT CLASS = 'three'>Includes: " + lakeArray[lakeNumber][16].substr(0,lakeArray[lakeNumber][16].length - 2)  + "</FONT>";
    }
else
    document.getElementById("lake_notes").innerHTML = lakeNotes;
}
```

I've tried various iterations of this code and done lots of reading up on google maps API related issues but couldn't find one with a resolution that is applicable to me here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you bind the maps api like above or like `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>`

Comment: You don't need a key to display multiple markers.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including any HTML/CSS required and some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. While I was creating an example page as per geocodezip's recommendation, I found the problem, it was unrelated to this code. (Stupid mistake!) It works!